# QuerySyntaxException unexped token OSAN near line 1 when writing a hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hello I have below sql query that works in sql developer. DB is oracle.

When I try to run the query from SQL developer it works fine. However, when I try to do that in Java class that it QuerySyntax Exception.

```
select ID from Location where NAME='xxx'
```

```
getEntityManager().createQuery("select ID from " + Location.class.getName() + " where NAME=xxx")
```

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: OSAB near line 1, column 98 [select ID from **packageName.Location o where NAME=xxx]

Comment: show your `Location` class and include more of the code around the query creation

Comment: ID and name fields are mapped by  @Column(name = "ID") like this. Other code are not interfering with this function.

Comment: If your entity is properly mapped, then remove the package path in the query. Use `Location.class.getSimpleName()` or `Location.class.getCanonicalName()`